# Heroku gives application error for Safari only, works fine for Chrome or Firefox

Tags: heroku, safari, meteor

Our Heroku application seems to be having a weird issue. The application works fine from Chrome or Firefox however when loaded in Safari I am getting the [Heroku Application Error Page](http://s3.amazonaws.com/heroku_pages/error.html). We have a test instance running the same application with a custom domain and SSL endpoint but it doesn't have this issue. Also connecting directly to the Heroku url app-name.herokuapp.com works fine in Safari. It is only when using Safari and connecting to our custom domain does it give the application error.

The only thing I can think of is an error in the Heroku router, or the SSL endpoint.

I've tried clearing my cache, and changing the DNS for the Safari browser, and asked multiple other people to test and they are experiencing the same issue with Safari.

Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Comment: My problem was caused by exceeding the max rows for postgresql. Got no error in the logs. Was hard to debug. Upgrade to hobby-dev..

Comment: Yeah, it turned out this was actually an issue with app-cache. The app was cached in Chrome and Firefox, but not in Safari. So it looked like it was loading in Chrome and FF, but it was actually just loading from cache.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you forward your domain to Heroku with a "masked" domain while using Safari or iOS there are weird results.

In my case the server side session cookies will not be accessible.

It works perfectly on Chrome and Firefox.
I use Godaddy to manage the domain name but I do not think they are the caused.

When I remove the "masked" and strictly forward the domain to Heroku all platforms work.