# Heroku application not accessible on Safari

Tags: heroku, safari, dns, connection

So I have a rails multi-tenant project running on Heroku where we identify what to serve based on the domain you access from. These domains are added to the app's heroku domains and the cname records provided by Heroku for [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) are added to the domain's DNS and we also add a permanant redirect rule for `domain.com/* -> www.domain.com/$1` so that people can access without a www.

This all works perfectly fine on Chrome/Firefox, but on Safari and IOS devices we've been getting reports and were able to reproduce that the websites simply timeout.

- I have tried to monitor traffic with wireshark, I can see the GET HTTP request going out but nothing comes back.
- I have tried to access the app directly using the appname.herokuapp.com URL, it works perfectly fine in that case.
- I have tried accessing with a VPN (Cloudflare WARP), the issue is not present in this case. However I tried manually setting the DNS to Cloudflare's and that did not fix the issue. I have also tried 3 different ISPs and that was also not the issue.

So to sum up, the issue happens if:

1. You're accessing using a domain that POINTS TO a CNAME record (xxx.herokudns.com) that POINTS TO the app.
2. You're not using a VPN/Cloudflare WARP.
3. You're on Safari.

I have found a reference for this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29195842/7130982) but this dates back to 2015. I also have doubts that this [Safari update](https://portswigger.net/daily-swig/apples-safari-browser-blocks-cname-cloaking-in-big-sur-privacy-boost) could be relevant.

Has anyone been through this previously or can provide insights on to how I can further debug this?

Comment: Just hit this very strange error myself. Were you able to find any resolution?

Comment: We had a planned migration to GCP coming up anyway. so we stopped using the cloaked CNAMEs and switched to normal A records. That fixed the issue. I think it's just a dumb anti-ad feature apple put into Safari so there's no other way around it.